# Does revoking a certificate result in revocation of its key?

Tags: cryptography, certificate-revocation

If I request my identity certificate to be revoked for any reason other than key compromise, would the private key also be revoked in result?

Answer (score 6):

There is no revocation of different parts of the certificate, i.e. a certificate is either revoked in full or not revoked at all. This also means that the certificate itself is revoked and not the key of the certificate, i.e. other certificates which use the same key are not affected by the revocation. And this means that you are free to reuse the key for another certificate.

Comment: ... although practically you should use different keys for different purposes, if just because you'd have to revoke all certificates if the key *does* get compromised (and revocation is no panacea, e.g. revoking a certificate on enveloped data does not help if the private key has been compromised).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes in fact, if you use the same key for encryption and signing, and I hear you have a certificate to revoke, I'm immediately putting my black hat on, scanning the CRL and then scouring the Internet for said private keys.